# Using SQLite & C++

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I'm completely new to programming and have some limited experience with Visual Basic and Java, but now I'm branching out into C++ and I'm trying to make it my primary language. I've got the basics down, i.e variables pointers classes etc, but something that has always troubled me with all programming is writing a program that can read and write to and from a database rather than a text file for the purposes of making the program online-capable.

Now, what I want to do is make a program that people can download. Basically all of the variables they change locally will be written to a database. Next time they open the program I want them to read in the data from the database that is relevant to them. I have a general idea of what to do, just not how to do it.

I was led to believe SQLite was a good choice for this, so I've went and downloaded SQLite. When I opened it I am immediately lost.

I just want to start small, once I know how to read and write data to the database using SQLite I want to figure it out myself. I've looked up some guides but nothing really helped as I didn't fully understand them.

So, to keep things simple, all I really need is some example code that will take input from the command line (using cin) and write that input to a SQLite database. Then, I want to read that data and output it on the command line. Assuming a fresh C++ file and no preexisting SQLite database (if that's even relevant). How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad because you're trying to do something very broad.

Break up your approach. Start with a program that just opens and closes a database. To do this you will have to work out how to include the sqlite3.h header and link with the right library.

Once you have done this, try to create a table and insert a row. Use the sqlite3 command line tool to verify that you have succeeded.

From there, try reading your file and putting the data you need into the database.

As you have problems along the way, ask specific questions, something like "I get a 'symbol not found' error when I try to link my program", "when I try to insert a string into the database I get a crash" or "I start a transaction, insert some data, but when my program exits I don't see anything from the command line tool".

There are libraries that help with using databases like soci. These tools can be good, but I suspect they will get in the way of what you're trying to do for now. Once you made made something basic work you can look at how to improve your code.

So: break it up, do one thing at a time. C++ is a big language.